# Remove whitespaces from input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I know there is a lot of topics about this and i checked a lot of them without success.

I have one input field in my form that creates a problem when it includes whitespaces. I already made it required so it's not possible to leave it empty or only add some whitespaces.

What i noticed is that i can add a text and just add a whitespace in the end or in the beginning and my work will fail.

Actually it should not be allowed to have any whitespaces at all, also not in the middle of the text but thats is to 99% not going to happend. What i understand you can only take away whitespaces in the beginning and in the end with trim function?

Could some helpful person help me what i have to add to my code that it works...?

Goal is that when i press submit the values from my five input fields should have no whitespaces at the beginning or in the end.

Here is my whole code.

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <title>Mathys Lieferungen</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.progressbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeHiddenInput (objDropDown)
        {
            document.getElementById("hiddenInput").value = objDropDown.value; 

        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.timepicker').timepicker(); 
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});
            $('.button').button();
            $('#myForm').submit(function() {
                $('#formBox').hide();
                var lnr = $("input[name=lnr]");
                var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                function()                                        
                {                                        
                $('#csv').load(lnr.val()+'_JobStatus.csv?'+new Date().getTime(),function(data){$(this).html(data).fadeIn("slow");});          });
                $('#working').show();
                $("#progressbar").progressbar();
                var value = 0;
                var timer = setInterval (function ()
                {
                  $("div#progressbar").progressbar ("value", value);
                  value++;
                  if (value > 100) value = 0;
                }, 60);


                $url = "/BT_Mathys_LNr_export_0.1/services/BT_Mathys_LNr_export?method=runJob";
                $i = 1
                $('#myForm :input').each(function() {
                    $inputName = $(this).attr('name');
                    if ($inputName != 'submit') {
                        $url = $url + "&arg"+$i+"=--context_param%20"+$inputName+"="+$(this).val();
                        $i++
                    };
                });
                $('#runArea').load($url, function(){
                    $('#csv').hide();
                    $('#working').hide();
                    $('#resultBox').show(); 
                    $html = $('#runArea').html();
                    $('#csv').text($html);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body { 
            background-color:#FFD8B2; 
            font-family: 'Century Schoolbook', Calibri,Arial;
            font-size: 1em;
            }
        #logo {
            position:absolute;
            top:10px;
            right:10px;
            }               
        h1 {
            margin-bottom:20px;
            font-size: 1.5em; 
            font-weight:bold; 
            text-align:center;
            }
        #formBox, #resultBox, #working{
            width:50%;
            margin:auto;
            margin-top:20%;
            }
        #resultBox, #working {
            display:none;
            }
        #runArea{
            border:none;
            height:0;
            width:0;
            }
        .button { font-family:Garamond; font-size: 15px; }
        .ui-timepicker { font-family:Garamond; font-size: 11px; margin-left:40px }
        .ui-datepicker { font-family:Garamond; font-size: 11px; margin-left:40px }
        .ui-timepicker-hour-cell, .ui-timepicker-minute-cell { cursor:pointer; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="\\rzwsrv006\daten\Opacc_Betrieb\Marcel Mathys\Mathys\FLYER_LOGO.png" alt="Flyer" width="260" height="48">
    </div>
    <div id="formBox">
        <h1>Lieferungen Mathys</h1>
        <form method="get" id="myForm">
            <table width="290px" height="auto" style="margin:auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="lnr">Liefernummer:</label></td>
                    <td class="arg"><input type="text" name="lnr" class="required"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <!--<tr>
                    <td><label for="vAbladezeit_spaet">Abladezeit spät:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="vAbladezeit_spaet" class="timepicker"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="vAbladezeit_frueh">Abladezeit früh:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="vAbladezeit_frueh" class="timepicker"></td>
                </tr>--> 
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="vAbladetermin">Abladetermin:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="vAbladetermin" class="datepicker"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>                  
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="vLadezeit_spaet">Ladezeit spät:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="vLadezeit_spaet" class="timepicker"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="vLadezeit_frueh">Ladezeit früh:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="vLadezeit_frueh" class="timepicker"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="vLadedatum">Ladedatum:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="vLadedatum" class="datepicker"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>  
                <tr>

                    <td>Mitarbeiter:</td>
                    <td><select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
                    <option value="e.schaer@flyer.ch" name="email">Ester Schär</option>
                    <option value="i.gerber@flyer.ch" name="email">Irene Gerber</option>
                    <option value="m.maeder@flyer.ch" name="email">Marion Mäder</option>
                    <option value="apelsinrepubliken@hotmail.com" name="email">Jens Frejd</option>
                    <option value="marcel.lack@symbium.ch" name="email">Marcel Lack</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value=" Ausführen " class="button"></p></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="working" onkeydown ="my_onkeydown_handler();">Verarbeitung läuft, bitte warten und job nicht abbrechen. Job läuft im Hintergrund<div id="progressbar">
    </div>


    </div>
    <div id="resultBox">
        <h1 id="csv"></h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" onClick="location.href='./'" value=" << Neue Lieferung ausführen " class="button"></p>
        <!--<p style="text-align:left;">Rückmeldung:<br>
        <textarea id="csv" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></textarea>  
        </p>-->
    </div>
    <iframe id="runArea" />
</body>
```

Comment: [`str.replace(/\s/g, '')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Can i just change this and it will work?  var lnr = $("input[name=lnr]");
                var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                function()                                        
                {                                        
                $('#csv').load(lnr.val().replace(/\s/g, ''))+'_JobStatus.csv?'+new Date().getTime(),function(data){$(this).html(data).fadeIn("slow");});          });

Answer (score -1):

How about just using a regex to replace the white-space:

```
str.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

Comment: Could you help me say what changes i need to make to my exicsting code? Im new to this things and always have problems where to place everything i add on the right places

Comment: I am not sure where you need to add it, your question is bit short on the details I would need to work it out. My quick stab in the dark would be the line: $url = $url + "&arg"+$i+"=--context_param%20"+$inputName+"="+$(this).val(); I think it would work if you did this: $url = $url + "&arg"+$i+"=--context_param%20"+$inputName+"="+$(this).val().replace(/\s/g, "");

Comment: I tried it but i didnt work, what about adding str.replace(/\s/g, ""); somewhere here $('#myForm').submit(function() {
     $('#formBox').hide();
     var lnr = $("input[name=lnr]");